# Pull to refresh icon does not render upon swipe down on Android App

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am working on an Android App, and I want to implement a pull-to-refresh effect on the stats screen. I was trying to follow the [documentation here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/pulltorefresh/package-summary). The demo in the documentation works fine on my app, showing a loading icon upon swiping down. So I then started integrating the effect into my existing code, but then only the `getDrivingSkillScore()` is called upon swiping down, but there is not little loading icon showing in the top anymore.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun StatsScreen(
    statsUiState: StatsUiState,
    statsViewModel: StatsViewModel,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    val state = rememberPullToRefreshState()
    if (state.isRefreshing) {
        LaunchedEffect(true) {
            statsViewModel.getDrivingSkillScore()
            delay(1000)
            state.endRefresh()

        }
    }

    Box(modifier.nestedScroll(state.nestedScrollConnection)) {
        LazyColumn(modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        }
        PullToRefreshContainer(
            modifier = modifier.align(Alignment.TopCenter),
            state = state,
        )

    }

    when (statsUiState) {
        is StatsUiState.Success -> ResultScreen(
            scores = statsUiState.score,
            modifier = modifier
        )

        is StatsUiState.Loading -> LoadingScreen(modifier = modifier)
        is StatsUiState.Error -> ErrorScreen(modifier = modifier)
    }
}


@Composable
fun LoadingScreen(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Text(text = stringResource(R.string.loading), modifier = modifier.padding(16.dp))
}

@Composable
fun ErrorScreen(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Text(text = stringResource(R.string.loading_failed), modifier = modifier.padding(16.dp))
}

@Composable
fun ResultScreen(
    scores: List<DrivingSkillScore>,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Current Driving Skill Level",
            color = NavActiveColor,
            fontSize = 20.sp,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(16.dp)
                .align(AbsoluteAlignment.Left)
        )

        CurrentSkillChart(scores.last())

        Text(
            text = "Last Performance Level",
            color = NavActiveColor,
            fontSize = 20.sp,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(16.dp)
                .align(AbsoluteAlignment.Left)
        )

        LastPerformanceChart(scores.takeLast(5))
    }
}
```

I guess the `when()` block is triggering the rendering of new Screens, leading to the loading icon not showing. But I don't know how I can fix this issue. I am new to android development, and I appreciate any helpful suggestions! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically are showing two Composables in your `StatsScreen` Composable:

- A `Box` Composable
- A `ResultScreen` / `LoadingScreen` / `Error` Composable

But you do not define any arrangement Composable that defines how these Composables should be arranged. Jetpack Compose will thus implicitly use a `Box` Composable and [stacks the two Composables on top of each other](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/basics#composable-functions). My guess is that now your `LoadingScreen` Composable is simply overlapping the PullToRefresh animation.

You probably want the Composables to appear below the loading circle. You can try to achieve that like this:

```
Box(modifier.nestedScroll(state.nestedScrollConnection)) {
    LazyColumn(modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        item {
            when (statsUiState) {
                is StatsUiState.Success -> ResultScreen(
                    scores = statsUiState.score,
                    modifier = modifier)
                is StatsUiState.Loading -> LoadingScreen(modifier = modifier)
                is StatsUiState.Error -> ErrorScreen(modifier = modifier)
            }
        }
    }
    PullToRefreshContainer(
        modifier = modifier.align(Alignment.TopCenter),
        state = state,
    )

}
```

You also can try to completely remove the `LazyColumn`, but I think it might be necessary to have a scrollable container below the `PullToRefreshContainer`.